# Dual N/P-Channel MOSFET Dies with Smoke

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, mosfet, circuit-design

I have built the following N-MOS & P-MOS push-pull dual MOSFET circuit. Its purpose is to control some external LEDs from a 3.3V microprocessor.

However, there seems to be a problem, where the dual MOSFET chip “SI4554DY-T1-GE3 Dual N/P-Channel” dies a horrible fumy smoke death, when 12V is connected as shown in the schematic below.

The smoke appears even when no load is connected and the MOSFETs are not switched (idle).

As far as I can see in the [datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/126c/0900766b8126ce53.pdf), none of the limits (V[GS] < 20V, V[DS] < 40V) are exceeded.

Can you help in identifying the problem? Thank you!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAlrBh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Image of the circuit implementation]

Comment: Smoke signals are how the error messages resulting from exceeding the maximum power dissipation are transmitted.

Comment: Your simulation results are only going to be as good as your simulation.  If you're controlling banks of LEDs, the load is not really well modeled as a 100 ohm resistor.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I forgot to say that the error message (smoke) appears when no load is connected at all (R_LOAD = infinity).

Comment: What is the gate voltage when you connect 12V? Probably both mosfets are conducting, shorting each other. Also, why are you using push-pull for this? The N-mosfet isn't doing anything useful in driving your LEDs...

Comment: When you apply power, you're relying on R2 to charge up the gates of the two MOSFETs. How long does this take, and how much current flows through them in that time?

Comment: Well, I'm using a 1A current limited source, so the gate voltage is limited too. It's around 9V (the voltage source's output).

Comment: The reason for using push-pull, is because the same circuit is used to drive some "smart-LEDs" which require a positive +12V signal. I have a PCB with 8 of these circuits and that allows me flexibility with respect to what kind of load I am switching.

Comment: Are you able to add a switch between 12 V and where it powers M1? That ways, you could bring up the 12 V supply and let it stabilise and the gate drive stabilise before you power the push-pull circuit. That would rule in or out the slow rise time of the PSU leading to both devices conducting at once. I would also try reducing the 47 K pull-up to 4K7 for a much sharper rise time while it charges the gates, though I think that's less likely the cause.

Comment: @DaveTweed Well, it's a bit difficult to measure, with the smoke and all. But the output V_LOAD measures to 0V, until a few minutes later, where I guess the MOSFET dies completely and the output becomes ~12V.

Comment: Probably has something to do with the 222A chugging through there when they are both on at the same time..

Comment: The idea was that you would *analyze* this aspect of the design, not perform the destructive experiment again. Both MOSFETs have low threshold voltages, so having a high "shoot-through" current on any switching transition is a very real problem. Based on your subsequent description of your application, it sounds like driving the two gates separately might be a good idea; then you would be able to turn them both off.

Comment: @DaveTweed agreed. or add a choke in there (inductor+diode)to block the switching transition current spike.

Comment: @TonyM Adding a switch would be a bit difficult, but I could try. I have added an image of my setup (see above).
->Trevor As far as I thought I had designed it, this should never happen for a prolonged time. Do you have an example for the choke?
->DaveTweed Ah, yes, of course, but my simulations seem to indicate that everything is working fine. The shoot-through current is simulated to peak at ~10µA.

Comment: I take your point. Could you remove the IC and put a 2700 pF capacitor across the IC gate pin and GND, then use a DSO to measure the rise time and profile on power-up?

Comment: @Trevor, maybe smoothing capacitor on the board close to the MOSFET  between +12 and GND?

Comment: @utu2012 There is one a few centimeters to the right on the first one I killed.

Comment: My first suspicion was that I was exceeding a rating in the SI4554DY, since I have made the same design for lower currents before with BSS138 and BSS84P MOSFETs which has been working just fine.

Comment: With that push-pull configuration both MOSFETS will be switched on for a period of time during every input transition with rising edges far worse due to the 47k R2. I suggest you reduce that value *significantly* - 1k or less (depending on the MOSFETs' gate capacitance). If you simulate it make sure your simulator models the gate capacitance properly.

Comment: @brhans OK, I will do that. Although the MOSFET died when not switching (idle), so it's probably not the cause.

Comment: 47k pull up? Yikes!

Comment: The part actually installed on the board is 51K. Why do people insist on showing us schematics that don't reflect the reality of their situation? The reference designators are all wrong, too.

Comment: Remove M2 - it does not appear to do anything except to provide a destructive "shoot through" path for M1.

Comment: Simulations use the typical values from data sheets in the vast majority of cases and therefore using simulations here is of limited value. The thing I do not see is some 'dead time' control. See http://www.linear.com/docs/4139 for how macromodels are typically put together.

Comment: @DaveTweed I ran out of 47k, which was what I had installed on the first board that died (picture is from my second, "clean" test).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's a dual MOSFET part, which includes both N- and P-MOS. I need 'M2' for loads that need to be switched on their negative pin.

Comment: @Johns, but did you run out of 5's and 1's in Circuitlab? Running out of 47k parts doesn't mean you can't draw the schematic to match what you actually tested.

Comment: @ThePhoton The original circuit I tested had 47k. And it's not like that is what kills everything.
I now tried using a 1k pullup, as brhans suggested, with the same result. The MOSFET seems to acts as a constant short circuit from 12V to GND.

Comment: When you say 'testing with NO drive signal', do you mean ground or O/C. If Vin is always high or low then Q1 state is defined. But O/C vin allows Q1 to possibly turn partially on - which can be disastrous. Regardless, a highish value resistor from Q1 base to ground is in order - say 10K || Several people have mentioned shoot through via M1 & M2 and several schemes have been proposed. | POSSIBLY useful is a zener from Q1 C to each FET gate and resistor that turns each  FET off from Gate to source. 2 x say 5V6 zener on a 12V supply means that there is minimal crossover and 2 x 6V8 gives none.

Comment: Before reading the comments, my first "guess" was that both M1 & M2 were turned on, causing a dead short for the 12V supply.  Regardless of the simulation, apparently this situation lasts long enough to damage the chip.  Obviously, the solution is to not apply the 12V to M1 until the gate voltage stabilizes.  Putting a choke on M1's collector should make it work.

Answer (score 7):

Your Push-Pull configuration is inverted. N-channel MOSFET is supposed to be connected to +ve rail and P-channel MOSFET should be connected to -ve rail. Your circuit blows up because both the MOSFETs will turn on for some amount of time when input changes from low-to-high or high-to-low. This will cause short circuit and you will get the magic smoke!

Please see the reference link below:

http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/MOSFET/MOSFET.html

Comment: I am certain that the design should be correct. I have used that push-pull design multiple times. The difference now is that I am using a component with dual MOSFET, compared to using individual MOSFETs in the past. Searching for half bridge mosfet driver, both designs seem to be popular.

Comment: @Johis there is a significant difference in the switching times of the mosfets. Even if you can guarantee the gate signals arrive simultaneously, there WILL be a "both on" time. I suggest you either drive the gates separately or add some inductance in the power line with a fly-back diode to cut out the spikes.

Comment: @Johis also, it worked before is no indication that it was right either. We are talking about miniscule differences here with current spikes that last nS. What kills one device may not kill the next one.

Comment: @Johis, I feel daft because I looked at this earlier, when I checked your FET sources were connected correctly on your PCB. But your scheme would work...if your gates had really fast rise time and fall time. To avoid the problems of this, it's much better and just as easy to use the opposite scheme, shown by vivekkholia's links. That ensures that both FETs are off as the gates voltage transitions through the 'dead zone' between very-high and very-low. I was shown this on a motor drives a few decades ago, should have spotted it.

Comment: @Johis if you have to use the same configuration you are using, then consider driving MOSFETs individually. Allow a dead-time to ensure they are not conducting at the same time.

Comment: @vivekkholia OK, I will consider this next time. However, I doubt this is the current main problem at hand since I have magic smoke even when not switching.

Comment: @Johis it may be getting killed during power up too.

Comment: Just switching the mosfets around will not drive rail to rail though.

Comment: @Johis if you have access to DSO hook it up to your circuit's power supply possibly at the source of the P-channel MOSFET where 12V is connected and and the gates. configure the DSO for one shot trigger and turn on the power supply. If you see a large spike then you can be sure that over-voltage probably killed it. MOSFET gates are very sensitive to over-voltages.

Comment: @Johis, as I suggested an hour ago, could you remove the IC and put a 2700 pF capacitor across the IC gate pin and GND, then use a DSO to measure the rise time and profile on power-up? This is quick to do.

Comment: @vivekkholia Power supply seems fine on the DSO. Gate voltage rises cleanly to 12V.

Comment: @vivekkholia your source (the second link) is simply wrong. Please reconsider your answer.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It was not *simply wrong*. It was probably irrelevant to the question asked. I also said *some extra stuff* before posting it. Removed it though.

Comment: @TonyM My DSO doesn't want to trigger in a way where I can see the rise. At highest resolution it rises instantly on my scope. (will try to find a better scope)

Comment: Power Drivers like to oscillate. 10nH and 10nF will resonate at 16MHz, dangerously fast for these FETs. The switching losses are huge, and this loss repeats 16,000,000 times per second.

Answer (score 3):

Push pull-circuits of that design are notorious for fusing through due to inadvertently turning on both mosfets simultaneously.

Obviously, this can happen during switching, but it can also happen as the power is applied to the circuit. The current pulse is normally very short, however, the smaller the mosfet devices the more probable a failure will occur on one or both of them.

As such, when using rail-rail push-pull drivers like this it is required that some protection be provided to ensure that the current can not spike through the bridge.

Below is an example that uses an in-line inductor as a current choke.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsu7nw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

L1 and D1 in the schematic above should be sized to limit the rise time of the current to be significantly less than the switching time of the mosfets.

Resistor R2 should be included to force the circuit into a particular state while the logic that is driving it is powering up. This is especially true if the signal originates from a micro that is initially configured as a high impedance pin. Whether this resistor is pulled to ground of logic 1 will depend on which state you want the output to start in.

C1 is intended to try and protect the mosfets from any start-up voltage spikes on the power supply.

R1 should also not be over-sized. It needs to drain the capacitance of M1 and charge M2 quickly enough when the transistor turns off.

Ultimately, with this type of driver, it is preferred that separate control signals be used with a built in dead-time where both switches are turned off before one is turned on. In addition to giving you more protection for your driver, it also adds the functionality of being able to disconnect the output entirely.

Answer (score 2):

When Q1 turns off, the drive is limited by the 47K resistor. The charge time is about R2 x total gate capacitance, or 47K x 3nf = 141us, and during this slow transition the n and p transistors burn as they pass massive current. When Q1 turns on, the drive is not limited by R2, but by Q1 output resistance (less than 1 ohm), so the M1 and M2 are on together for a much shorter time, perhaps under 300ns.

The proper solution is to drive each of the gates separately, so that the "off" drive current is higher than the "on" drive current for each of M1 and M2. This will allow the capacitance at each of M1 and M2 to charge at different rates, and they will both be off for some guard time instead of both being on at the same time for a significant interval.

Keep the Q1 circuit to turn on/off M2. Use a separate emitter follower to drive M1. In each case, the "on" drive current will be high and the "off" current will be relatively low, allowing a guard time between on and off.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'testing with NO drive signal', do you mean "no drive" is low resistance ground or O/C.

If Vin is always high or low then Q1 state is defined.
But O/C Vin allows Q1 to possibly turn partially on - which can be disastrous.
Regardless, a highish value resistor from Q1 base to ground is in order - say 10K.

Several people have mentioned shoot through via M1 & M2 and several schemes have been proposed. POSSIBLY useful is a zener from Q1 C to each FET gate and a resistor per FET that turns each  FET off from Gate to source.
2 x say 6V8 zeners on a 12V supply means that there is minimal crossover.

In the diagram below, assume V+ is 12V & FET Vgsth is 2V in each case.
FET lower required Vc to be at 2V + 6V8 = 8.8V or higher to turn on.
FET upper requires Vc to be at 12V - 8.8V = 3.2V or lower to turn on.

For Vin < 6.8V. FET lower is fully off.
For Vin > 12 - 6.8V = 5.2V FET upper is fully off.
This significant dead band protection MAY help prevent shoot through.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnnL6R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I will test your suggestion and come back to you. The above test was with an open circuit at the base (since I assumed the leakage would not be sufficient to turn on the NPN BJT).

Comment: @Johis Before trying zeners etc, just add the base pull down. Leakage current is multiplied by Beta (at least) and increased collector current may occur "once it gets going". | This is definitely the source of problems in some cases. Whether it is so here is TBD. | NB - NEVER give Murphy an even break - he's quite capable of making trouble even when you do things correctly :-).

Answer (score 1):

12V and there is no current limit. Assume an incidence where both conduct for whatever reason and lead to failure. Put a current limit resistor in the supply or a resistor in the supply and a resistor to ground for output voltage balance within current tolerance of the device(s).

I am soon intending to experiment with dual gate (MOS) FETs' and this article has provided inspiration! Thanks :-)